# Using dojox/form/BusyComboButton in AMD

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to use [dojox/form/BusyComboButton](https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/form/BusyButton.js#L154) in AMD code but cannot find examples for how to do so (and I'm not sure if its possible).

Since it's declared in the `dojox/form/BusyButton` file without being returned from the module I can't find a way to pull it with require call or in html without using non-AMD code.

Is there a way to do this without modifications to dojox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo adds the module to the global scope (`window`). This means you can still retrieve them to use in your code, for example:

```
require(["dojox/form/BusyButton", "dojo/domReady!"], function() {
    var BusyComboButton = window.dojox.form.BusyComboButton;
    var btn = new BusyComboButton({
        label: "My button"
    }, "test");
});
```

If you prefer to use the AMD loader for `BusyComboButton` as well, you can create your own shim, for example:

**custom/BusyComboButton.js**:

```
define(["dojox/form/BusyButton"], function() {
    return window.dojox.form.BusyComboButton;
});
```

Then you can use:

```
require(["custom/BusyComboButton", "dojo/domReady!"], function(BusyComboButton) {
    var btn = new BusyComboButton({
        label: "My button"
    }, "test");
});
```